# reCaptcha v3 Console Error for Content Security Policy

Tags: episerver, episerver-forms

I have added Forms.Samples 3.7 in my episerver solution to include reCaptcha v3. After inclusion, I was able to see reCaptcha element within form elements in episerver which i have included in one of the episerver form.Running the application gives me the reCaptcha icon on the page that is used to validate before form submission.

To emulate a robotic behavior & reject form submission to verify the working of reCaptcha, i have included chrome extension Mod header for the same & the rejection of form works.

However, when I land on the page where the recaptcha form is, i get an error in console related to content security policy. Assuming this might be something restricting on my application site, i tried to implement the same in Alloy site & the issue is still the same .Here's a snap of the error in alloy site.

[image]

This does not hinders the reCaptcha functionality but i would like to understand why this error in console. If this is a bug related to v3.

The error is same in firefox console as well but as a warning.